# How to parse same argument twice or more than once to python script?

Tags: python, argument-passing

I have written a python script which uses argeparse module for handling arguments. 
e.g.

```
Test_Dual.py -g Linux
```

Now, I want to give it two options for same argument, like

```
Test_Dual.py -g Linux -g ESX -g Windows
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Python supports multiple way to parse command line arguments. Which module or library you are using?

Comment: i am using python built in import argeparse module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=("Program desciption"))


parser.add_argument("-g", "--full-name-of-g", action='append',
                    help="what is g option for")

args = vars(parser.parse_args())

print(args['full_name_of_g'])
```

Prints:

```
['Linux', 'ESX', 'Windows']
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the `'append'` action to [`add_argument`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action).  This will accumulate values into a list -- once for each time the command line argument is present.  e.g.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()  # yadda yadda
parser.add_argument('-g', action='append')

fake_args_for_demo = '-g Linux -g ESX -g Windows'.split()
namespace = parser.parse_args(fake_args_for_demo)

print(namespace.g)  # ['Linux', 'ESX', 'Windows']
```